# SCALA: Is it possible to prepare a regression suite(integration tests) for Restful API's with scalatest

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest

I am writing a regression suite for API's using SCALATEST, I am kind of stuck-up with following scenario:
For instance I have two tests:

test-1{
Call for API-1
Call for API-2
Call for API-3
}

test-2{
Call for API-5
Call for API-6
Call for API-7
}

I have created a generalized function to Call API's I have setup separate JSON files for URI, method, body and headers.

Now my question is that as all these calls will be async, and will be getting back Future Results, one way to handle I know is flatmap / or For within one Test.

But what about 2nd Test, do I need to block main thread here or there is some smart solution for this. I can't afford to run multiple cases in parallel due to inter-dependencies on resources they will be using.

Answer (score 1):

It's better for your tests be executed sequentially, for this please refer to the scalatest [user guide](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/async_testing) on how to deal with `Future`s

Play will also provide you some utils to handle a `Future`, the usage is described in the [testing documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithScalaTest#Testing-with-a-server)